# How to set koma pseudolength in emacs org mode?

Tags: koma-script, emacs, org-mode

Using emacs org-mode and the koma letter script, how can I set the vertical address position?

The <sup>1</sup>manual at p.484 displays a nice <sup>2</sup>overview of position possibilities.
However, neither of these lines result as expected:

`#+LATEX_HEADER: \setplength{toaddrvpos}{5cm}`

`#+LATEX_HEADER: \@setplength{toaddrvpos}{5cm}`

## Example.org

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: default-koma-letter
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{signature.png}\\\usekomavar{fromname}}
#+LCO: SN
#+LANGUAGE: en
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setplength{toaddrvpos}{5cm}

#+AUTHOR: Bugs Bunny
#+TO_ADDRESS: Batman
#+SUBJECT: My subject
#+OPENING: My opening
#+CLOSING: My closing
#+FROM: From me

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor
tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis
eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor.
Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum.
Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.
```

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf

<sup>2</sup> [image: img]

Comment: You have to ensure that `SN.lco` is loaded before you change the pseudolength to an own value. So maybe   it is the same issue as in your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482411/43317)? And the same solution?

Comment: Thank you. Tried these as well:

`#+LATEX_HEADER: \AtBeginLetter{\renewcommand{\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{10cm}}}`

`#+LATEX_HEADER: \AtBeginLetter{\renewcommand{@setplength{toaddrvpos}{10cm}}}`

`#+LATEX_HEADER: \AtBeginLetter{\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{10cm}}`

`#+LATEX_HEADER: \AtBeginLetter{@setplength{toaddrvpos}{10cm}}`

Comment: It is recommended to use a user defined `lco` file for basic settings like setting of pseudo-lengths (and even variables like `fromname`). In this `lco` file you could also use `\LoadLetterOption{SN}`. If you'd do so, you could simply replace `#+LCO: SN` by `#+LCO:MyBasics`.  esdd has shown this solution already in her [answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482434/9057).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an own `lco` file (recommended solution):

```
\ProvidesFile{mySN.lco}[2019/04/13 letter-class-option]
\LoadLetterOption{SN}
\let\raggedsignature=\raggedright
\setplength{toaddrvpos}{10cm}
\endinput
```

Then

```
\documentclass[foldmarks,backaddress=false]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\LoadLetterOption{visualize}% can be used only in preamble
\showfields{address}% visualize the position of the address field

\usepackage{graphicx}
\LoadLetterOption{mySN}% load the user defined lco file
\setkomavar{fromname}{Bugs Bunny}
\setkomavar{subject}{My Subject}
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}\\\usekomavar{fromname}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Batman}
\opening{My opening}
\lipsum[1]
\closing{My closing}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image: screenshot]

With older KOMA-Script versions (3.25 or earlier) you have to replace `\setplength` by `\@setplength` in the `lco` file.

---

With `\AtBeginLetter` and `SN.lco`:

```
\documentclass[foldmarks,backaddress=false]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\LoadLetterOption{visualize}% can be used only in preamble
\showfields{address}% visualize the position of the address field

\usepackage{graphicx}
\AtBeginLetter{%
  \renewcommand{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}%
  \setplength{toaddrvpos}{10cm}%
}
\LoadLetterOption{SN}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Bugs Bunny}
\setkomavar{subject}{My Subject}
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}\\\usekomavar{fromname}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Batman}
\opening{My opening}
\lipsum[1]
\closing{My closing}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Note: With older KOMA-Script versions (3.25 or earlier) and this solution you have to replace

```
\setplength{toaddrvpos}{10cm}%
```

by

```
\makeatletter\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{10cm}\makeatother
```

because `\AtBeginLetter` is used in the preamble of the document.