# Org mode latex koma letter: How to get the command \setplength{toaddrhpos} working?

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, letters, org-mode

**Problem**

I use org-mode to generate a latex file, which then generates a pdf file. The document class I use is scrlttr2.  The pdf generates OK, here is the org file:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: scrlttr2
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [pagenumber=false,parskip=half,fromalign=right, foldmarks=false, addrfield=topalign]
#+DATE: \today
#+AUTHOR: Max Le
#+SUBJECT: A simple letter
#+FROM_ADDRESS: Sender address
#+FROM_ADDRESS: Sender city
#+LANGUAGE: en
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[english]{babel}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright} 

#+TO_ADDRESS: Receiver
#+TO_ADDRESS: Receiver address
#+TO_ADDRESS: Receiver city

#+LATEX_HEADER: \setplength{toaddrhpos}{-100mm}

#+OPENING: Dear John,
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enimad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
#+CLOSING: Yours truly,
#+SIGNATURE: Jane
```

I want to move the Receiver address horizontally. After checking the Koma letter's guide, I know that it can be done with: `\setplength{toaddrhpos}{-100mm}`. In org-mode, to set this variable, I included in the LATEX_HEADER like this: `#+LATEX_HEADER: \setplength{toaddrhpos}{-100mm}`.  This does not seem to work because the Receiver field stays the same.

Org-mode does generates a .tex file, so I check that file as well. The .tex file is here, https://pastebin.com/4dzjnPAq
You can see that at line 20 on this .tex file, there is the command `\setplength{...}`.  If you generate a pdf from this tex file, the receiver address is still in the same place !

I mess around with the .tex file and the only way to get it to work is to move the `\setlengthp{...}` to after the Receiver block, which is after `\begin{letter}`.  In other words, it looks like this:

```
\begin{letter}{%
Receiver\\
Receiver address\\
Receiver city}
\setplength{toaddrhpos}{-100mm}
......
```

A fixed version of the .tex file is here, https://pastebin.com/j7X96UrT. You can see it on line 48.

**Question**: How do I achieve the same thing from within my org file.  You can see in the original org file, that I tried to put that command after the `#+TO_ADDRESS` block, still the generated .tex does not put the command in the correct place (right after Receiver block). Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, from this: [How to set koma pseudolength in emacs org mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484570/how-to-set-koma-pseudolength-in-emacs-org-mode)

Apparently, you can create an lco file then load it. Or you can do this:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \AtBeginLetter{\setplength{toaddrhpos}{-9cm}}
```

The lco file is more preferred.